# What is wrong with this class definition? (Related with: SwaggerDefaultValues.cs)

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger

I have created class like below. I have similar classes in my project, non of them causing error except this one. I can't find any problem in my class but it's causing exception, In my *description* variable, *ModelMetadata* property is null which is cause error.

This is how *description* variable is defined in my SwaggerDefaultValues.cs

```
var description = context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions.First(p => p.Name == parameter.Name);
```

And It throws exception here, ModelMetadata is null which is cause  System.NullReferenceException:

```
parameter.Description = description.ModelMetadata.Description;
```

### (Please see screenshot for details...)

As i trace my code, this class definition causes issue,

**CardPlusCNumberUpdateQueryParameter class:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WestCore.AppCore.Services.PCsbins.Customer
{
    public class CardPlusCNumberUpdateQueryParameter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Customer Number
        /// </summary>
        [Range(1, 999999)]
        [Required]
        public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// CardPlus Customer Number
        /// </summary>
        [Required]
        public string CardPlusCustomerNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StackTrace:**

```
at WestCore.Api.Swagger.SwaggerDefaultValues.Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context) in C:\Users\can.pahali\source\WestCoreApiSS\Main\WestCore.Api\Swagger\SwaggerDefaultValues.cs:line 38
       at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreateOperation(ApiDescription apiDescription, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)
       at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)
       at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreatePathItems>b__2(IGrouping`2 group)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector)
       at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItems(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, ISchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)
       at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath, String[] schemes)
       at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
```

**UPDATE:** I've also added screenshot for context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions object.

[image: context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions view]

[image: See throwing exception]

Comment: What does `context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions` contain?

Comment: Dear @ColinM the question is updated.